# django save a new instance of object

Tags: python, django

I am trying to update a user "karma points" whenever a user posts something. For this, i first created a new model called Myuser that allows for points property:

```
class Myuser(models.Model):
    user=models.OneToOneField(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    points=models.IntegerField(default=1)
```

And then in my view.py post_new() function, I tried to update the score:

```
u=User.objects.get(username=request.user.username)
u.myuser.points=u.myuser.points+5
u.save()
```

but then i notice that rather than update the points field, it just saves a new instance with the same user id but updated score. I thought .save() is supposed to update exisiting copy.

This is what i did for object initiation

```
u=User.objects.get(username=request.user.username)
Myuser.objects.create(user_id=u.id, points=1)
```

Edit: I think the problem might be model initiation. When I initiate an instance and check

```
u=User.objects.get(username='barkthinks')  #a registered username
Myuser.objects.create(user_id=u.id, points=10)
```

```
<Myuser: Myuser object (6052d3844fbcaa988e993c30)>
```

When I do:

```
Myuser.objects.all()
```

I will get this result

```
QuerySet [<Myuser: Myuser object (None)>
```

when I do .save(), sometimes I keep bumping into this error:

```
TypeError: Field 'id' expected a number but got ObjectId('6052d1054fbcaa988e993c2b').
```

Comment: your Myuser model has onetoone feld with user but why are you passing user id during creation ??

Comment: Also to update the Myuser points value you should not update it through user.yuser but directly get the instance of myuser and then update its points

Answer (score 1):

try at first check if there is `Myuser` instance if not create new one, but if there is `Myuser` class instance for that user, then update that instance by doing this code.

```
u=User.objects.get(username='barkthinks')
try:
    myuser_instance = Myuser.objects.get(user=u)
    myuser_instance.points += 5
    myuser_instance.save()
except ObjectDoesNotExist:
    Myuser.objects.create(user=u, points=10)
```

Answer (score 0):

Get the Unique Myuser instance and update the model instead

```
u=User.objects.get(username=request.user.username)
myuser = Myuser.objects.get(user=u)
myuser.points += 5
myuser.save()
```

Comment: no, still doesnt work..it might have something to do with how i initiate it..
u=User.objects.get(username=request.user.username)
Myuser.objects.create(user_id=u.id, points=10)

Comment: creating a new Myuser instance will not update the existing one

Comment: Ensure the user field in your Myuser model is unique. To do this delete all Myuser instances with the same user you have created in your database and add ```class Myuser(models.Model):
    user=models.OneToOneField(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE, unique=True)
    points=models.IntegerField(default=1)```

Comment: i've added unique=True, still getting saved double copies

Answer (score 0):

to update any instance of a model,

```
variable = Models.objects.filter(conditions).update(attribute_to_update = update_value)
```

get the instance of the model using filter and condition, then use the .update to update values

**models.py :**

```
class Myuser(models.Model):
    user=models.OneToOneField(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    points=models.IntegerField(default=1)
```

**views.py :**

```
u=User.objects.get(username='barkthinks')
new_user_instance = Myuser.objects.create(user = u , points=10)
```

And then in the view.py post_new() function,

```
my_user = MyUser.objects.get(user__id = request.user.id)
temp = my_user.points
updated_instance = Myuser.objects.get(User__id = request.user.id).update(points = temp + 10)
```

Comment: still doesnt work.. some cant get that object :(